# Validação customizada ao trocar de aba no p:wizard

Tags: primefaces

Tenho o seguinte p:wizard

```
<p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true"
                        closable="true" />
<p:wizard flowListener="#{caixaRecebimento_MB.onFlowProcess}" showNavBar="false" widgetVar="wRecebimento" styleClass="ms-botao" id = "wRecebimento" >
            <p:tab title="Documento" id="tabI">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/recebimento/RecebimentoDocumento.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Fechamento" id="tab1">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/recebimento/RecebimentoFechamento.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Ajuste Matricula" id="tab2">

            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Assinatura" id="tabF">

            </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>

    <hr />
    <p:commandButton id="btVoltar" widgetVar="btVoltar"  value="Voltar"  onclick="PF('wRecebimento').back();"  styleClass="ms-botao" icon="fa fa-arrow-left" 
        disabled="#{caixaRecebimento_MB.dasabilitaVoltar}" update="btVoltar btAvancar"/>
    <p:commandButton id="btAvancar" widgetVar="btAvancar" value="Avançar"  onclick="PF('wRecebimento').next();"  styleClass="ms-botao" icon="fa fa-arrow-right" iconPos="rigth" 
        disabled="#{caixaRecebimento_MB.desabilitaAvancar}" update="btVoltar btAvancar"/>
```

Contudo gostaria de fazer uma validação customizada ao trocar de abas, e assim o fiz através do método onFlowProcess

```
public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {
    if(event.getOldStep().equals("tabI")){
        if(loteDeVenda.getItensLoteDeVenda().size()<2){
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Não é possivel avançar sem incluir um item");
            //return event.getOldStep();
            return " ";
        }
    }

    if(event.getNewStep().equals("tabI")){
        this.desabilitaAvancar = false;
        this.dasabilitaVoltar = true;
    } else if(event.getNewStep().equals("tabF")){
        this.desabilitaAvancar = true;
        this.dasabilitaVoltar = false;
    } else {
        this.desabilitaAvancar = false;
        this.dasabilitaVoltar = false;
    }

    return event.getNewStep();
}
```

Até funciona, mas quando a validação deve impedir de avançar tenho alguns problemas.

se retorno " " vai para ultima aba.

Se retorno event.getOldStep() para permanecer na aba atual, o messages aparece mas logo se apaga,  como se tivesse dado um refresh na tela.
ou seja até permanece na aba como esperado mas o usuário fica sem saber o porque.

Comment: Amigo, já tentou retornar o Id da p:Tab que voçê gostaria que ele permanecesse?
Tipo return "tabI";

Comment: Fiz o que sugeriu. A navegação funciona, mas continua a mensagem aparecendo e sumindo rapidamente